# Issue after the first animation execution

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, opacity

I have a button that triggers an animation. When I click the button again, it toggles the class but the opacity is still in my code after the animation.

This happens for all the consequent clicks. How can I fix this?

```
$( "#menu-button" ).click(function() {
    $("#right-sidebar").toggleClass("display");

    if($("#right-sidebar").hasClass("display") == false){
        $("#right-sidebar").css(opacity = "0");
    } else {
        $("#right-sidebar").animate({
            opacity: "1"
        }, "slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: Your problem is in `.css(opacity = "0")`. Change it to `.css("opacity", "0")`

Comment: '(opacity = "0")' isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from `.css(opcity = "0")` as **@Mohammad** mentioned in the comment, just fix this and your code will works fine :

```js
$( "#menu-button" ).click(function() {
  $("#right-sidebar").toggleClass("display");

  if(!$("#right-sidebar").hasClass("display")){
    $("#right-sidebar").css("opacity", "0");
  } else {
    $("#right-sidebar").animate({
      opacity: "1"
    }, "slow");
  }
});
```

```css
#right-sidebar{
  width:80%;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="menu-button">menu</button>

<div id='right-sidebar' class="display">right sidebar</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try `bind` instead of `click`

```
$( "#menu-button" ).bind("click", function() {
      $("#right-sidebar").toggleClass("display");

      if($("#right-sidebar").hasClass("display") == false){
        $("#right-sidebar").css("opacity","0");
      } else {
        $("#right-sidebar").animate({
                  opacity: 1
              }, "slow");
      }
    });
```

Comment: Although this appears to solve the problem, `click(` isn't the problem in the OP's original post.